# No overload matches this call in React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I want to separate the styles for elements to make them easier to read. I wrote next code

```
let styles={
    search:{
        container:{
            position:"absolute",
            top:0,
        },
    }
}
```

And then use as

```
<View style={styles.search.container}/>
```

Everything work fine but TypeScript throw error for **style** - 'No overload matches this call'

Tell me please how to suppress this error?

Comment: are you putting the styles object inside StyleSheet.create() function ?

Comment: no, I not put styles inside StyleSheet.create

Comment: I don't see `StyleSheet.create()` in your code  :)

Comment: StyleSheet.create(
    search:{
        container:{
            position:"absolute",
            top:0,
        },
    }
);
Not will work

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to solve this problem

```
let styles={
    search:StyleSheet.create({
        container:{
            position:"absolute",
            top:0,
        },
    })
}
```

Thanks everything

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour makes sense, as the compiler doesn’t know which return type to expect.

```
function styles(): Object {
  return {
        container:{
            position:"absolute",
            top:0,
        },
    }
}

<View style={styles().container}/>
```

Here the compilete know which the return values is an Object.